# How to use returned arraylist?How to retrieve data from arraylist?

Tags: android, class, arraylist, android-asynctask

In the following code,i am saving the three values fun_id,fun_logo,fun_req with the help of another class Use.In the code an arraylist is returned,now i want to retrieve the fun_id,fun_logo,fun_req.I want to add fun_logo into imagearray.I would like to know how to use the **Class Use** for retreving data.I am learning currently so only small idea bout android.

```
 ArrayList<Use> stringArrayList = null;
    ArrayList<Use> res = null;
    ArrayList<String> linklist = null;
    String getdetailsurl;
    String  link [];
    String[] ar;
    Use[] getalldet;
   public String imagearray[]; 

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         new Getdetailsfromweb().execute();

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      // adapter=new myadpter(this, imagearray);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
public class Getdetailsfromweb extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            getdetailsurl=Webcall.getdet();

            if(getdetailsurl!=null)
            {

                result = "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Failure";

            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            res = new ArrayList<Use>();

            try {
                if (result.contentEquals("Success")) 
                {

                    res=passdetails();
                    System.out.println("lsize is " + res.size());
                    for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++)
                    {
                        // To retreive value what should i do here



                    imagearray[i]=obj.funlogo;
                     System.out.println("logo is " + imagearray[i]);

                    }


                } 
                else 
                {

                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }



public   ArrayList<Use> passdetails()
        {
            JSONArray array = null;
            stringArrayList = new ArrayList<Use>();
            linklist= new ArrayList<String>();
            Use usee;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(getdetailsurl);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             for(int i = 0;i <array.length() ;i++ ) 
             {

                 String fun_id= null;
                 String fun_logo= null;
                 String fun_req = null;
                try {
                    fun_id = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("up_id");

                    System.out.println("up_id is " + fun_id);

                      fun_logo=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("logo");
                     System.out.println("logo is " + fun_logo);

                      fun_req=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("requirements");
                     System.out.println("req is " + fun_req);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                usee=new Use();

                usee.funid=fun_id;
                 System.out.println("fun is " + usee.funid);
                usee.funlogo=fun_logo;
                 System.out.println("fun is " + usee.funlogo);
                usee.funreq=fun_req;
                 System.out.println("fun is " + usee.funreq);

                 linklist.add(fun_logo);
                 stringArrayList.add(usee);

             }

            return stringArrayList;

        }


    }
```

Use.java

```
public class Use {
    public static String funid;
    public String funlogo;
    public  String funreq;

}
```

Comment: add variable String imageUrl to your class Use and use it

Comment: You need a C++/JAVA book to learn OOPS fundamentals!

Comment: @PareshMayani ha ha..looking at my code you thought so..ya ...vague idea about OOPS concept....somehow run the code and getting output...

Comment: @HariSankar my observation says that because you have declared all the variables globally and that's not the optimized way to declare and use variables. There scope should be limited.

Comment: @PareshMayani was looking at your example found on some blog to download image and show in listview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a `Use` class with getter and setter methods.
2. Define a method `getFunLogos()` in `Use` class which would return the image array of all the fun logos. Access this method from wherever you want.

   ```
   protected String[] getFunLogos(ArrayList<Use> listFunLogos) {
   for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++)
   {
      // To retreive value what should i do here
      imagearray[i]=obj.funlogo;
      System.out.println("logo is " + imagearray[i]);
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know how to use the Class Use for retrieving data

All fields are `public` in `Use` and `res` is ArrayList of object of `Use` class. access values from each object as :

```
for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++)
 Use useObj=res.get(i);
 String funlogo=useObj.funlogo;
 String funreq=useObj.funreq;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add fun_logo into imagearray

```
//linklist : as you are adding fun_log in it
imagearray=new String[linklist.size()];

linklist.toArray(imageArray);
```